# AWS SimpleEmailService throws exception on sending mail

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using AWS SES to send mail. The code is pretty simple

```
 var textBody = new Content(body);
 var message = new Message(new Content(subject), new Body(textBody));
 var destination = new Destination { ToAddresses = (new List<string> { to }) };

 using (var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient())
 {
     client.SendEmail(new SendEmailRequest(from, destination, message));
 }
```

But this last line always ends with exception *"An exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException' occurred in AWSSDK.Core.dll but was not handled in user code"*

Inner exception is following *"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."*

What can be the reason? In other places SES API works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found. Based on AWS documentation SimpleEmailService support now only TLS 1.0 encryption.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/security.html

> HTTP
>
> If you are using the Amazon SES API (either directly or through an AWS
>   SDK), then all communications are encrypted by TLS through the Amazon
>   SES HTTPS endpoint. The Amazon SES HTTPS endpoint supports TLS 1.0
>   only.

The only way now - override default SecurityProtocol to use "Tls" encryption for sending mails through Amazon SES provider

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Why Tls1 is no longer used by other providers - [read here](https://blog.varonis.com/ssl-and-tls-1-0-no-longer-acceptable-for-pci-compliance/)